# get the ViewTreeObserver object from the attached OnPreDrawListener object

Tags: java, android, android-layout, observers

How can I get the observer inside the listener?
example:

```
ViewTreeObserver myObserver = myLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
myObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // I want to get the myLayout or myObserver here, 
        // but I don't want to use the lines below
        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(myId);
        myLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
```

Comment: make `myObserver` as `final` variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make it final or declare it as a instance variable ie declare it before `onCreate` and initialize it `onCreate`

```
final ViewTreeObserver myObserver = myLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing

[ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener.html) is a interface implemented by annonymous inner class. SO to access the variable it must be `final`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to add instance variables to OnPreDrawListener extended object.

Comment: @Hovo instance variable meaning you will have to declare it outside onCreate like `ViewTreeObserver myObserver;` then intialize it inside `onCreate`.

Comment: Understood, you meant the instance that onCreate method belongs, not the listener instance.

Comment: @Hovo read the java docs An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as final or effectively final. that's why i asked you make it final. second way declare you relatvie layout and `ViewTreeObserver myObserver;` before onCreate and it will work

Comment: I know what is final, but we can't make every local variable to be final just because we can't access them in an inner anonymous code, I  used to use the final when I want the JVM not to let anyone and me to change that variable. And again we can't make a locale variable to be object's field

Comment: @Hovo then declare it as instance variable

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to play with listener instance, 
I don't know how accurate is it, but it works :)

```
final class MyOnPreDrawListener implements OnPreDrawListener
{
    private RelativeLayout myLayout;

    public void setMyLayout(RelativeLayout layout){
        myLayout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        // now I have myLayout here         
        return true;
    }

}
```

then I call

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = myLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
MyOnPreDrawListener myListener = new MyOnPreDrawListener();
myListener.setMyLayout(myLayout);
observer.addOnPreDrawListener(myListener);
```